# In .NET consume a Java web service that returns a hash table

Tags: java, .net, web-services, hashtable

I want to consume a web service built in Java from a .NET application. The web service returns a hash table in one of the methods and when I run soapUI against that method I can see that it works.

But when I add the web service as a Service Reference in VS2008 the hash tables are converted into arrays... Could I configure the service in some way to handle hashtables?

Is it even possible to consume a WS that returns a hashtable in .NET???

best regards,
Zeno